# PHP syntax not highlighting in VS code

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

I am EXTREMELY new to front-end development. So I am not sure what the problem is.

I have had this issue for HTML before but in this instance, PHP is causing the problem.

This is what my VS code looks like:
[image: This is what my VS code looks like]

I have installed all the extensions
adding <?php breaks the code completely

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks right. Find and download blade snippets extension and intellisense, that should help you